# any downfall for having a high max_input_vars value?

Tags: php, post, ini

I was wondering if there were any major issues with changing my max_input_vars value from 1 000 to 10 000 in my php.ini file? I get that runtime can be slow for large data, but are there any security or other major faults with this change?
Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, users simply won't work with a form with that many entries.... that's the big downside (exceptions might be something like an Excel grid, but even that shouldn't need 10000 input vars)

Comment: @MarkBaker I have a case of needing 7000 input vars. There are no security of major faults though right?

Comment: Even 7000 is pretty excessive..... how many users do you have that haven't complained about a form that size?

Comment: There is no direct security issue with the number of fields, other than your ability to validate/cleanse/etc

Comment: No complaints since it still runs pretty quickly.  Thanks for the help